# How to make BottomSheetDialogFragment cover the full screen?

Tags: android, fragment, bottom-sheet

I'm using `BottomSheetDialogFragment` to show some data.But when I'm starting the `fragment` it's appearing 50% of the screen .So, my question is how to make it full screen when it shows.

`BottomSheetDialogFragment` Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bot_frag, container, false);
    TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textVi);
    back=v.findViewById(R.id.back_of_bot);
    back.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            }
    );
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Then you don't want a **Bottom**DialogFragment. A **plain** DialogFragment is what you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dialog fragments, plz refer this:

```
public class DialogFragments extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_dialogfragment_layout, null);
        getDialog().setTitle("Title");
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (metrics.heightPixels * 0.30));// here i have fragment height 30% of window's height you can set it as per your requirement
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimationUpDown;

}
```

and when you want to open,open Bottomsheet dialog like this way :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bot_frag, container, false);
    TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.textVi);
    back=v.findViewById(R.id.back_of_bot);
    back.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                   DialogFragments dialogFragment = new DialogFragments(this);
                   dialogFragment.show(fm, "Bottomsheet Fragment");
                }
            }
    );
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply this style to you `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_NoActionBar_Fullscreen
```

Comment: It requires minimum sdk of 21

Answer (score 0):

This solution applies to `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. I haven't tested on other types of bottom sheet views. Two things you need to do:

1. To Set minimum height of your bottom sheet's root view to your display's

```
container?.minimumHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
```

2. Override the theme in your BottomSheetDialogFragment to return this style

```
override fun getTheme(): Int {
    return R.style.Theme_Design_BottomSheetDialog
}
```

First action will set the bottom sheet height to your display's. Second action sets the bottom sheet theme to one that fills the width - this is more of an issue on tablet. Now you have a fullscreen bottom sheet.